# HTML Preview not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

[image]
I've received some HTML that I need to add a header and footer to but its showing up like the picture - does anyone know why? I'll include the code

Comment: "I'll include the code" — go on then

Comment: You dont have a doc type tag at the start of the file that might be causing this. But without the actual code we cant help!

Comment: the code is 90386. this is limited to 30000 - how else can i share with you?

Answer (score -3):

You can use HTML beautify. There are varies website where you can beautify your html and use that to format it. You can simple copy it from there and add in your header file.

Comment: HTML being well formatted wont effect if it can render or not

Comment: you mean after formatted HTML, it still shows junk code?